# How to define a trigger rule "all failed but none skipped" in apache airflow

Tags: airflow

I am having the following trigger rule in airflow:

```
PythonOperator(
trigger_rule="all_failed"
)
```

However, in my case I want it the task to run only if the direct parent failed, not in case direct parent was skipped, as it is some kind of cleanup task.
There is also a trigger rule for `none_skipped` here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/concepts.html#trigger-rules

Is it possible to define multiple trigger rules with and, or configure it in another way?

Comment: Note that 1.10.10 is over 3 years old, so might be difficult to get answers for 1.10.10. I believe `all_failed` does mean "all failed but none skipped"